# Getting "Warning may not respond to a" message iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am calling a method from another method and keep getting a warning: **firstViewController may not respond to '-playJS'**

```
-(void) playJS
{

//my code here

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't declared the method yet in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the declaration in the header file, it's also OK to declare it before the call.

Answer (score 0):

If the methods are in different classes (and files) you need to import the headerfile too.